# Run python script from terminal adding parameters

Tags: python, unit-testing, parameters, terminal, arguments

I am working with Python 2.7. 
I create the following script:

```
import unittest
from tests.selenium_test_base import SeleniumTestBase
import sys

class TestPrintArg(SeleniumTestBase):

    def test_print_arg(self):
        print "BEGIN: "+str(len(sys.argv))
        for elements in sys.argv:
            print elements
        print "END:"

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

I executed from terminal using: `python test_print_arg.py`

But if I executed with arguments: `python test_print_arg.py arg1`

I am getting the following issue:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_verify_page.py", line 19, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()

C:\stash\sxd_qa\tests\log_in>python test_verify_page.py arg1
BEGIN: 2
test_verify_page.py
arg1
END:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_verify_page.py", line 19, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arg1'
```

Could you help me? The browser is not launched if I want to use parameters.

Comment: Because `unittest.main()` parses parameters from command line. And it doesn't expect to get parameters, you pass. You can completely ignore all parameters by passing empty `list`. If it is what you want. Like: `unittest.main(argv=[])`. Better solution is to remove parameters expected by your script before calling `unittest.main()` and pass rest using `argv=...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @YaroslavAdmin! Is working fine now!